# Auto build, deployment to hockey with Fastlane

Tags: ios, xcode, hockeyapp, fastlane, fastlane-produce

I am studying about automatic build and deployment. I found out fastlane and trying to use for deployment to hockey.

https://github.com/fastlane/examples/blob/master/Artsy/eidolon/Fastfile
https://github.com/fastlane/examples/blob/master/Wikipedia/Fastfile

But, I am not familiar with script.

If I have 2 configuration

1) Debug 
2) Release

2 scheme

1) Touch - Development 
2) Touch - Production

2 hockey key

52da9f2b3da50cf8b6d4aac15f06ae9b 
ZXz1tdfaDLfb4hY8SagCfX4RJNMhJVsxET95sHf9

How shall I modify script? What command do I need to run after I modify? I have already done "fastlane init" though.

Comment: I highly recommend *NOT* to publish your API Keys and API Tokens. Other can abuse this.

Comment: Thanks @Kerni. They are fake key.

Answer (score 0):

This question is over 4 years old now, so the scenario changed completely. HockeyApp was deprecated, and replaced by App Center.

Luckily, Microsoft maintains a *fastlane* plugin to manage the integration with App Center, which can be found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/fastlane-plugin-appcenter/